# Using r.los doesn't create file

Tags: grass-gis, viewshed

I have to create some viewsheds. I want to use the grass gis r.los. 
DEM as elevation, coordinates of a point collected via "coordinate capture" and the area is restricted by a second raster-layer.

[image]

My problem is this error:

[image]

Does somebody know what to do?

Comment: Perhaps these posts might help: [GRASS algorithm r.los does not produce raster](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83282/grass-algorithm-r-los-does-not-produce-raster); and [no output file with grass:r.los](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85314/no-output-file-with-grassr-los)

Comment: i tried to find the command grass r.los in the command-box, but it is not there. so basicly, the r.los is in the grass toolbox, but not in the direct command-box. how is that possible?

Comment: _"command-box"_, are you referring to the **Processing Toolbox**?

Comment: Please note that r.los is deprecated and replaced by the much faster https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.viewshed.html (means: use the GRASS GIS 7 provider in Processing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your viewing position is outside your computational region:

Viewing position x = 27.367...

xmin = 26.997... xmax = 27.303...